# Codeigniter 4 Modules form action

Tags: forms, modular

I am following the Codeigniter 4.0.4 User Guide and creating Modules.  I have created the Blog Module and the pages load correctly( index, view, create).

I am stumpped on the create page where the form action is calling APP/CONTROLLERS rather than my  modules controller located outside the APP folder.  I am using 2 helpers ( form, url ).

My Routes

```
$routes->group('myblog', ['namespace' => 'Acme\MyBlog\Controllers'], function($routes)
{
    $routes->get('/', 'MyBlog::index');
    $routes->get('view', 'MyBlog::view');
    $routes->get('create', 'MyBlog::create');
});
```

My Autoload

```
public $psr4 = [
    APP_NAMESPACE   => APPPATH, // For custom app namespace
    'App'           => APPPATH,
    'Config'        => APPPATH.'Config',
    'Acme\MyBlog'   => ROOTPATH.'Acme\MyBlog'
];
```

My Controller

```
<?php namespace Acme\MyBlog\Controllers;

use Acme\MyBlog\Controllers\BaseController;

use Acme\MyBlog\Models\PostModel;

use CodeIgniter\I18n\Time;


class MyBlog extends BaseController 
{

    public function create() 
    {
        $model = new PostModel();
        
        if ($this->request->getMethod() === 'post' && $this->validate([
            'title' => 'required|min_length[3]|max_length[255]',
            'body'  => 'required'
        ])) 
        {
            $model->save([
                'title' => $this->request->getPost('title'),
                'slug'  => url_title($this->request->getPost('title'), '-', TRUE),
                'body'  => $this->request->getPost('body'),
            ]);
                        echo view('Acme\MyBlog\Views\success');
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo view('Acme\MyBlog\Views\create', ['title' => 'Create a news Post']);
        }
    }
}
```

My Create Form

```
<h2><?= esc($title); ?></h2>
<?= \Config\Services::validation()->listErrors(); ?>
<div>
    <div>
        <?php echo form_open('myblog/create'); ?>
            <?= csrf_field() ?>
            <?php echo form_label('What is the Title', 'title');
            echo form_input('title') . '<br />'; 
            echo form_label('Post Body', 'body');
            echo form_textarea('body') . '<br />';            
            echo form_submit('submit', 'Create News Post!');
            $string = '</div></div>';
            echo form_close($string); ?>
```

The form action is set to myblog/create and the html for created shows this as well

```
// THE HTML CREATED 
<div>
    <div>
        <form action="http://localhost:8080/myblog/create" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
            <input type="hidden" name="csrf_test_name" value="7b9750243204e5a0578a74cec6b42b77" />
            <label for="title">What is the Title</label><input type="text" name="title" value=""  />
            <br />
            <label for="body">Post Body</label><textarea name="body" cols="40" rows="10" ></textarea>
            <br />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create News Post!"  />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, when i try to submit the form, I get the following error.  Where did this controller get called from???

```
<div class="wrap">
    <h1>404 - File Not Found</h1>
    <p>Controller or its method is not found: \App\Controllers\Myblog::create</p>
</div>
```

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code from `$routes->get('create', 'MyBlog::create');` to    `$routes->post('create', 'MyBlog::create');`